# Eclipse Java 6 with Mysql 8

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven

working on an existing project with java 6 and Mysql 5.1
we did a migration to Mysql 8.0.24, however I got this error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1041)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3481)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2445)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:172)
        ... 198 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:992)
        ... 211 more
```

when I did a research this error occurs when the version of Mysql connector is lawer then the MySQL.

However I used many versions of MySQL connector but I got the same error (mysql-connector-java-5.1.46, 5.1.47,5.1.49,8.0.11,8.0.24)

I'm using Maven, I used this command to install the dependency :

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\mysql-connector-java-x.jar -DgroupId=mysql -DartifactId=mysql-connector-java -Dversion=x -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

then update maven dependencies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.49</version>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: @KenitPatel I updated the post to show the code

Comment: You have updated a stack trace and not a code :(

Comment: I don't have any class that implement the connection,
the connection parameter is set on jboss server
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/dbUgap</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecatalogpr_temp</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>root</user-name>
    <password></password>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly says that you have a casting problem, because a java.math.BigInteger class instance is not an instance of java.lang.Long class.

The problem seems with your version of MySQL in combination with your version of MySQL-connector.jar. Try a newer version of MySQL Connector/J (see https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ for the latest version), for example upgrade to 5.1.47 or 8.0.12 if you are using an older version.

Comment: thanks for your answer, as I said I already used diffrent mysql connector version also the 8.0.2 but still got the same error